# How can i pass '<' and '>' to a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have bash script to run process in another thread and kill it, if it's hung up after timeout. All works perfectly, BUT when process require '<' as input or '>' to output to another file, it doesn't count them.
Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
($1)&
PID=$!
echo "Program '"$1"' started, PID="$PID
i=1
while [ $i -le 600 ]
    do
    ps -p $PID >> /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
      then
      wait $PID
      exit $? #success, return rc of program
    fi
    i=$(($i+1))
    echo "waiting 1 second..."
    sleep 1
done

#program does not want to exit itself, kill it
echo "killing program..."
kill $PID
exit 1 #failed
```

i use it like this:

```
safestart.sh './bzip2 -d  sample2.bz2 -k'
```

and all is as expected, but if i use somethig like this:

```
safestart.sh './cc_dry2 < dhryinput > results'
```

it doesn't get '<' or '>' symbols. I tried already with "". same result, I'm completely at lost here.

Comment: You may want to check out the `timeout` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### solution

The problem is the line:

```
($1)&
```

You should use instead:

```
eval $1 &
```

See also the following example for better understanding the problem.

#### example

```
cmd="echo TEST"
$(${cmd})
```

gives:

> TEST: command not found

```
cmd="echo TEST"
eval ${cmd}
```

gives:

> TEST

Comment: yes, that was definitely the cause, always got "command not found" error, thank you for answer